# Déjà Dup with SFTP

Tags: 16.04, backup, deja-dup, sftp

I'm trying to setup a backup on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I was just going to use the built in backup software, but Déjà Dup doesn't appear to have an SFTP option.

To clarify, I see the SSH option, but my backup location does not allow SSH, only SFTP. If you try to log in via SSH you get a "This service allows sftp connections only." error.

Is it possible to use SFTP with Déjà Dup?

Answer (score 0):

I [searched for `"deja dup" "sftp"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="deja+dup"+"sftp") and didn't find any direct confirmation of an SFTP back-end for Déjà Dup, but I found many (old) bug reports about a *partially* dysfunctional SFTP back-end, so that's an indirect confirmation.

**TL;DR: Yes, Déjà Dup supports SFTP back-ends.**

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because mostly in my case I'm using XFCE and didn't want to deal with **gnome-online-accounts**

As @david-foerster mention, ssh and sftp are supported by default but not realy intuitive unless you **choose** to explore and decide to go with **Network Server** and click on the little ***?*** to see more info.

[image]

PS: Obviously but not mentionned, you need to be able to scp without password which means using a sshkey for the authentification which you might end by want to configure a [ssh/.config](https://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) file